# Maintain the text structure when pasting into a textarea: javascript

Tags: javascript, position, textarea, indentation, caret

I'm trying to enter code syntax into a textarea when a link is clicked. I'm just messing around with making my own little text editor in Notepad for writing code.
I need it to display as:

```
           <div>

           </div>
```

not as

```
           <div>

</div>
```

I have the code already enabling the TAB key and injecting text at the caret position.
The only problem is that when the code syntax is multiple lines, the second to last lines do not follow the indentations or the structure that they have originally.

Hope I explained that well.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm going to try to bump this. Not sure if that's allowed so sorry in advance if so